# Error occurred during initialization of VM; Could not reserve enough space for object heap; Could not create the Java virtual machine

Tags: java, linux

I got this java problem

```
[root@peach sbin]# java
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
[root@peach sbin]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           256        182         73          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:        182         73
Swap:            0          0          0
[root@peach sbin]#
```

This is a virtual machine. I am thinking this problem because of the memory is not big enough. If some one agree with me.

It is running with a 
CentOS release 5.6 (Final)

Thanks

Comment: Yes, your guess is right ! Consider allocating more memory for that virtual machine. You can do this in the hardware settings for that VM.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
java -Xmx64m
```

Basically your machine doesn't have enough memory, but you may be able to get away with 64MB.  Let me know how you get on.

Comment: this works for me which starting gradle --gui by setting GRADLE_OPTS=-Xmx64m

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to know your current memory usage:

```
swapinfo -tam
```

I had the same error and the memory use was above 95%.