# Java fails with "Could not reserve enough space for code cache"

Tags: java, memory, crash

I have the following problem:

```
$ java -jar program.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for code cache
```

The amount of memory that is seen by the system seems sufficient:

```
$  free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          5959        640       5318          0          0        390
-/+ buffers/cache:        249       5710
Swap:         4099          0       4099
```

I tried lowering heap settings as low as 16mb, but it didn't help:

```
$ java -Xmx16m -Xms16m -jar program.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for code cache
```

What can be wrong? How can I debug this?

**EDIT:**
Forgot to include version - I use Sun Java 7u15, 64 bit. I actually can't get it to display a version string, because "java -version" fails with the same error.

Also, for some reason, if I use OpenJDK 6u27, it starts up - but since the app expects java 7, it doesn't work.

Comment: Already answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350486/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-o

Comment: @Vitaly - As I stated in the question, I already did try -Xmx as low as 16 mb - and `free -m` reports quite enough memory

Comment: maybe `16m` is not enough. Try more!

Comment: @Vitaly Also, for example, if I run "yes asdf | head -10000000 | sort | wc -m", I get the expected result - and since this line should allocate at least 50mb, it seems that memory is not an issue.

Comment: What do the values for InitialCodeCacheSize and ReservedCodeCacheSize show when you do `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | grep CodeCache`?

Comment: @boomz - I tried all powers of 2 from 16 to 512. I hope that should be enough :)

Comment: @Perception - no values at all, `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` fails with the same error.

Comment: @Rogach - wow, thats more serious. What system are you running on?

Comment: @Perception - that's Hardened Gentoo, running in VM. Output of `uname -a`: `Linux malibu 3.8.5-hardened #1 SMP Thu Apr 4 05:38:32 MSK 2013 x86_64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5640 @ 2.67GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux`

Comment: @Perception - I did not install the system, our admin did :( Also, now it seems he was recompiling the kernel today (if you look into the date in uname ouput), can that be the reason?

Comment: @Rogach - most of the reserved code cache problem hits that come up on Google are related to PaX enabled kernels. Not my area of expertise unfortunately - I think you might get better traction on ServerFault.

Comment: @Perception - Since it's "hardened" linux, they are very focused on security - so they probably included the patch. Thanks, I'll try to post this question on SF.

Comment: @Perception - seems your guess with PaX was right. I'll add an answer with my solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that my java was running on [Gentoo Hardened Linux](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/hardened/), and kernel had [PaX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PaX) enabled. To disable pax memory control, I used the following command:

```
paxctl -c -m /path/to/your/java/bin/java
```

After that, everything was smooth.

Answer (score -1):

You can set these sysctl variables (in BSD it is in /etc/sysctl.conf)

```
security.pax.mprotect.enabled=0
security.pax.mprotect.global=0
security.pax.mprotect.ptrace=0
```

than.... /etc/rc.d/sysctl restart 
do the "trick"